# Applying different colours to line charts in Vega-Lite

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, vega, deneb

In my multi layered chart, where the 2 lines shares the same second Y-Axis; I am attempting to apply a different colour to the second line to distinguish it as the prior year. However, the same colour is being applied to both lines:

[image: current chart]

Here's how I encoded the colours:

```
     "layer": [
        {
          "name": "Production CY",
          "mark": {"type": "line","tooltip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Month Nr", "type": "ordinal"},
            "y": {      
              "field": "Production CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "title": "Production (ton)"
            },
            "stroke": {
              "field": "Production CY Legend",
              "scale": {"range": ["black"]},
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Production PY",
          "mark": {"type": "line","tooltip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Month Nr", "type": "ordinal"},
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Production PY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "stroke": {
              "field": "Production PY Legend",
              "scale": {"range": ["Blue"]},
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            }
          }
        }
      ],
```

However, when I look at the compiled vega, the 2 lines appear to be grouped in the same domain:

```
    {
      "name": "stroke",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {
        "fields": [
          {"data": "data_0", "field": "Production CY Legend"},
          {"data": "data_4", "field": "Production PY Legend"}
        ],
        "sort": true
      },
      "range": ["black"]
    },
```

Is this because these two marks are layered? How can I apply 'Red' to the Production PFY line mark? Like so:

[image: intended result]

[Link to specification](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoAMoi0AdiUAxGrIAEATThIATmgBMABg8BmG3ZIslA0OvYAsnL09gBy7qgAjAGyQSFhkbL0aCAA8lCYiiAA0gAKAJKxSAhw2QCignBQ9gBmrmwI9gBKcLJwAO5ITA0GSqUVJmyuBageSgCqEEhkcPYAwo6eCZQAbAAc84vL9iUbM76UACyzIAAqbsvTHlu7AJxKJW3KDPnsDutoFwsewSL2270+30wv2OpzECQuYj8vgAvgpTOZUFYQLYHM43J4fP5sYFgqFBBEojBYvEksSUqT0pTsnkCqNypVqnUGk1Wu1YnJ+N1egMhvpCmN7BMpmhaQslit-okvFsvFi5UcTmgxBJ4Uo7q4HlqtmIiR82F8fnI1qdAcDQeDzZDoZrUHCEUjUejMDVMcknC54t4-MlUmSKZkqXFPCGGeSMll0DE2MRxeyYlUfSB6o0Wm0OkL+oNhqnxpNHgd5daCZRdSB1SsXR4LJQxFj9YaZhILFizRaoVbFWIriamw6+87YV4LhcXr4vJ6QGZvZY-XjA4SY2k45TqdG6aHGRHskmU2yKunOehszy8-zZIKeoXRSNiuypdNZYcFaddh4a9d6xhNBtmbYNbnuOBpm2P9dlNCFLT+WFh18UcQF7J0rRdMQpxnOcFyXH0sRxf18RmDd91jcNoijVAiRxA9tyPdAABFGhLDlM2vXM+QLEVizPSUyz3QDFQRGsxArDUbQuShfDBcCDUggEtgRMcMMQgFtgSPxdi8NSEKA2iLAubZtinfCMSIuwSPXMD6Mo+NI3iOiSS3KiYGyVioHYi9OO5biOiTe9eKLMUBPfGVJO-GUvF2FtP0rF1Zx2Wl2yU1BdmbC59jQ+D+w01ATO03xdP0-LDN8YzTPMtFF0s1cAwJOzXLDRzd0KzdWqZdAACkgh8jMuRzXl80fPiwtfUtpRmKKq1ol5KFnWasLiok0umIdLhy9CDMVXwQVVJbcsdAzG1nTKPDECzl19OkbKalz6TctqaIuTrDwTEA+vkATfKGm8+SCh9hVCl8JQixJZsVF5mxK5bTgSRHKC8N4FI7BIvHOXZaR28q9oOiwjtxidPHOixLuuwiGtIoNHoY9z2okijnu67E4CYAbLyzfyRq6MbQfYiGAK-Ob9prVHAJdC4VXk9a0BK2Sezy6E9qBWDATKknaISCwTReedaoIlc7rXB73sY6j4iZ+yWaYtmOd+warx528gZC59BaEyG6xFxUMfOE14ZlBIu1SiCP1ims4JOvHTkqvZfA147x0wuOdb1g2vSpk3GrI5qnq6iN2vkm3C8+8J8UdrmuN593+MmwTpuFytFRAQpJdODwZN8Nbw88P8LGjlOCrbzXU803YzMTynjeI0287phydxokuWo+jz0Ar9wq784bXYFOuJvBr2EqOVv25FpKFrhtH0peGClZjlXTlH5P1MMkzJ8xi4Z9uufc9pubBmNErIF3XtkAAgjgbeDc-rOz3jxfmHtwpe2bmfF+F9EqdzirsN6t9HjbEWkzYmA4MFjwcGdBIplda-1AfdBeQCXrxFAfTRykDoGc13gDQKB8kH12PtNU+0V0CYKkjKMQC0QJ6j7okGclAnjkLmq-EhFDO4vCoSBK6ht6o5xpuRUu692o5QMRbDeIAK4AE9OH-QCneYGT5+FvhPlDMhPssEyjkR4VGctEi+AWnCRR59FGNguHJBIulaHU1sovW2ls0DGLXqY7IljrHwO4XzEGyCG5CxcdkURDZO5-jEDlHxTwayBNcSowyXcwkRO0TdOh89AHMzLk5NAqMTHuWyD1BgP1YFO25gg0amTHFTXLG49BeSg6JEIftaRikPwSC7hUqZb9TpxznBYHwHhIm6OiYw5e8QOmJK6b1XpqTBnpLdnwo+TjBG5JEdMxGMlA74Jis2HwKzHlrPKi6Huqptm7P-no-OrDDkxQOXbHpggLk133sFG5YM7kfgea-DuMo5LIxKTI7SzYdZfOUcrceMwLCwQSD3IF1kmn6JOUwiFLTwFnJhTvGxtdEWeybqi-JhkdaUFJfM9GhCtIEsKFUxspL9oUvqdnYF+yGWmPaojSFn0IEMDILCl2iCRm3LGcJX2rj0UzBUgK9K3gRXBLjtlOElVKW4gATSsBCqaJKvlackAqr1UsrSbY652qkW6u9iJA1l8EYeDioiE1H5vDlJ+c-VZYrLW7GtRYW19DmmdLpYka4GbWYmDgDgDVQyMkOJ1Y3cZQbVmGpDpQSekaPE1uuFUoJsbiXun1rFVN1LQVLyLs67NtLc35sLVc3hfqOUoomcItFIb2kLRRnW1A98djmpbaovJyIAC6qIQCYFcEECAzRJgICMKAKAOgoAMEEGoTMAByJtDBXCuB6Jgew1hHA3sKEgAw6Am2OHsAAGXID0ZQIAFxnsEBeq9N0QB3qJRQ1w7BXCvvfZ+79q6YQAaA7IEDYHz2XuvdkG915d00BCJgCx9h1ofqUF+7I61MPLGw6B2q4HIMEfQKoTADAECGBvRKXyN6N32AANT2BvTCajIBaPoFWNesgkwLGalwxB-D0HOPcd4-xjMgmRNietJJ6TIBZPenk64Cx-xN1KHgDQMgWB5ZeD0iAPoNBlAJjMo5qAchmg2bQKABojGQOaBAJMGgz7shMDYNgdohRPO6AQLIb91wr0WLYAwaYoAItRePUF1IMBJjZAQC55QDRQPIjK0oZLcB4jGBAJV6roAUjV25CRsjFH-hKGQK4AA1r5ndFicCZiYJXEAAAPHIzRmgQHSo5iANAABePoMZKEwGwNgggoQFtQLuvQ26eieeUHYdVQWRu9e83AQQgXXV0uW-1zMkwDspGZVJkbNBv1+cGOdiBsgyAldQPObdVigtnYu9kCtN2BvZAAI4MCCFCdQUJSCFDh79y5LW6AUbKJkHos3yP2AABRdYAOpUgIPYFb8Gn5yAAJTMZALF-LQPQsg5k3JhT7W+sQ-QLIdogQnvQB0D6UAyh2hIDsEYS5tjD4QCAkoOFgNR0lul5qWXmrhmK6rCrotvr1f-A3UoPd32fSGBAAAYmnKCAAQqsQoJuxAQNWLsawECbd+IgYnC3NuLirGYqCC4IAt0Vaw4F0AyPMylaUPdqrp2meBeN8Z8gbONh6+C64ZQUfUDG6-VAYDh3-dlYXI1rhaPcfK5AJ1nrQXyOc5AENmBY2JtTemPwF1s2Fv0pW2tjbaBttwF28Ec0ufjvR-O5dnNvaYFV7u6n3nn6Xtvdqx9wQX2fs+n+0oQHoBgeXfReDzM0PYd0DUDQRHNG59oFkJewQ276fxE3zH7I8fTOKY2Lv7I3PCuPcKPz37QuRdi4zxLmyn6jLoAfCvYuNEri-qAVqjrlAXLjwgisAbrvrkEMsOLmbjONsFbjbnbg7k7i7i8G7hcB7koGbt7r7nnoHgFr1qHuutupHrfiAFvuLo-gppqMngweLlnjnt9nnuVg1gMjcBAp0AAOK1A3CFDl40G3bhbDb16TbpQt7zaLYeZrYM6m7WDWCrCrAOZI6rbrY0CbY95977aD6gAnaM4j7ZBj5xKv7oD3Yz6n6va9ZXpMCfbfa-Zr4gAb5SZkBkBPoUDQYQDcaFDMHoByx2EgD76ZCH4I41BOHfoX6CBX5KDebJHD7M74IMbAZf7gaC4gAG5oEAEm6aHaG6EB61ZB40F0Ao6lZlbJ5PoyCCCI5Bbf75GA4gAQAwBuBwA4YJG9YdF2Bp4DbYZhb561R1YnogCF7ZC-qSFuAV4h4yHoDCC9B6Gd6GHd6uA7ZKB7YD68FD6WGZE2FtKREOGf4A4ZGXZzGRHRFw5H4n47o1GZhVJ47k407boQC7psBdb5FhHobrDZFMZKBtG9aFFG415XpQA9YVH+Y5GV7PF0H8HTEDIJrzHdbSHV6rHxE7r6Fd5bbbG967H94PZHbmFXHWEDrj5I7LEp4PY6C04+FLD+F8BBEhGpH34-pwYgGT5Q4w4xHw7H44lIBn6oBJEpGdHfG-EUlcmU6qJAkgYgl5FgmoEQkW66A1CwlVEImYC1H56WYFH6BrYtGgCglBaDGjEjFp6ZB1FbpAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any better?

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 1,
        "Financial Month": "Oct",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 21.68,
        "Usage PY": 23.42,
        "Target": 21.89,
        "Production CY": 4768196,
        "Production PY": 5145233
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 1,
        "Financial Month": "Oct",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 101.07,
        "Usage PY": 55.14,
        "Target": 51.53,
        "Production CY": 4768196,
        "Production PY": 5145233
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 2,
        "Financial Month": "Nov",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 20.14,
        "Usage PY": 27.57,
        "Target": 25.77,
        "Production CY": 5425327,
        "Production PY": 5044930
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 2,
        "Financial Month": "Nov",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 82.12,
        "Usage PY": 67.23,
        "Target": 62.83,
        "Production CY": 5425327,
        "Production PY": 5044930
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 3,
        "Financial Month": "Dec",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 45.15,
        "Usage PY": 44.36,
        "Target": 41.45,
        "Production CY": 4612380,
        "Production PY": 3746604
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 3,
        "Financial Month": "Dec",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 108.51,
        "Usage PY": 93.61,
        "Target": 87.48,
        "Production CY": 4612380,
        "Production PY": 3746604
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 4,
        "Financial Month": "Jan",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 39.93,
        "Usage PY": 58.3,
        "Target": 54.48,
        "Production CY": 3190793,
        "Production PY": 2938725
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 4,
        "Financial Month": "Jan",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 97.38,
        "Usage PY": 111.09,
        "Target": 103.81,
        "Production CY": 3190793,
        "Production PY": 2938725
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 5,
        "Financial Month": "Feb",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 31.19,
        "Usage PY": 41.06,
        "Target": 38.37,
        "Production CY": 3768347,
        "Production PY": 3175390
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 5,
        "Financial Month": "Feb",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 103.53,
        "Usage PY": 115.71,
        "Target": 108.13,
        "Production CY": 3768347,
        "Production PY": 3175390
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 6,
        "Financial Month": "Mar",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 24.33,
        "Target": 22.73,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 4686034
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 6,
        "Financial Month": "Mar",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 99.38,
        "Target": 92.87,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 4686034
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 7,
        "Financial Month": "Apr",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 28.84,
        "Target": 26.95,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2916675
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 7,
        "Financial Month": "Apr",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 159.67,
        "Target": 149.21,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2916675
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 8,
        "Financial Month": "May",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 149.29,
        "Target": 139.51,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2436180
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 8,
        "Financial Month": "May",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 22.58,
        "Target": 21.1,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2436180
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 9,
        "Financial Month": "Jun",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 16.31,
        "Target": 15.24,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 3307022
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 9,
        "Financial Month": "Jun",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 114.53,
        "Target": 107.02,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 3307022
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 10,
        "Financial Month": "Jul",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 136.08,
        "Target": 127.17,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2783133
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 10,
        "Financial Month": "Jul",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 17.78,
        "Target": 16.61,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2783133
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 11,
        "Financial Month": "Aug",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 21.4,
        "Target": 20,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 3485137
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 11,
        "Financial Month": "Aug",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 128.52,
        "Target": 120.1,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 3485137
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 12,
        "Financial Month": "Sep",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 15.86,
        "Target": 14.82,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 4529008
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 12,
        "Financial Month": "Sep",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 99.09,
        "Target": 92.6,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "'Production Current FY'", "as": "Production CY Legend"},
    {"calculate": "'Production Prior FY'", "as": "Production PY Legend"},
    {"calculate": "'Electricity Target'", "as": "Target Legend"},
    {"calculate": "datum['KPI Name'] + ' PY'", "as": "CategoryPY"},
    {"calculate": "datum['KPI Name'] + ' CY'", "as": "CategoryCY"}
  ],
  "height": 300,
  "width": 600,
  "config": {
    "legend": {
      "orient": "bottom",
      "columns": 2,
      "layout": {"bottom": {"anchor": "middle"}}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "name": "Electricity CY",
          "mark": {"type": "bar", "xOffset": 0, "size": 10, "tooltip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Month Nr",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "Usage CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "title": "Electricity Intensity (kWh / ton Production)"
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "CategoryCY",
              "type": "nominal",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  "Elec from Renewables PY",
                  "Elec from Non-Renewables PY",
                  "Elec from Renewables CY",
                  "Elec from Non-Renewables CY"
                ],
                "range": ["#4496BC", "#5AC8FA", "#39A34B", "#4CD964"]
              },
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            },
            "order": {"field": ["CategoryCY"], "order": ["ascending"]}
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Electricity PY",
          "mark": {"type": "bar", "xOffset": -11, "size": 10, "tooltip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Month Nr",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
            },
            "y": {"field": "Usage PY", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null},
            "color": {
              "field": "CategoryPY",
              "type": "nominal",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  "Elec from Renewables PY",
                  "Elec from Non-Renewables PY",
                  "Elec from Renewables CY",
                  "Elec from Non-Renewables CY"
                ],
                "range": ["#4496BC", "#5AC8FA", "#39A34B", "#4CD964"]
              },
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            },
            "order": {"field": ["CategoryPY"], "order": ["ascending"]}
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "TARGET",
          "mark": {
            "type": "bar",
            "xOffset": 11,
            "size": 10,
            "color": "#FFCC00",
            "tooltip": true
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Month Nr",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
            },
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Target",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "fill": {
              "field": "Target Legend",
              "scale": {"range": ["#FFCC00"]},
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "shared"}, "axis": {"y": "independent"}}
    },
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "layer": [
            {
              "name": "Production CY",
              "mark": {"type": "line", "tooltip": true},
              "encoding": {
                "x": {"field": "Financial Month Nr", "type": "ordinal"},
                "y": {
                  "field": "Production CY",
                  "type": "quantitative",
                  "title": "Production (ton)"
                },
                "stroke": {
                  "field": "Production CY Legend",
                  "scale": {"range": ["black"]},
                  "legend": {"title": ""}
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "Production PY",
              "mark": {"type": "line", "tooltip": true},
              "encoding": {
                "x": {"field": "Financial Month Nr", "type": "ordinal"},
                "y": {
                  "aggregate": "sum",
                  "field": "Production PY",
                  "type": "quantitative",
                  "axis": null
                },
                "stroke": {
                  "field": "Production PY Legend",
                  "scale": {"range": ["red"]},
                  "legend": {"title": ""}
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "resolve": {
            "axis": {"y": "independent"},
            "scale": {"stroke": "independent"}
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent", "stroke": "independent"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: YES!!
When I go to add text marks to this, do I add the ones for the lines within the inner layer?

Comment: Yes, I would start with the inner layer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Stroke resolve has been set to independent.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 1,
        "Financial Month": "Oct",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 21.68,
        "Usage PY": 23.42,
        "Target": 21.89,
        "Production CY": 4768196,
        "Production PY": 5145233
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 1,
        "Financial Month": "Oct",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 101.07,
        "Usage PY": 55.14,
        "Target": 51.53,
        "Production CY": 4768196,
        "Production PY": 5145233
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 2,
        "Financial Month": "Nov",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 20.14,
        "Usage PY": 27.57,
        "Target": 25.77,
        "Production CY": 5425327,
        "Production PY": 5044930
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 2,
        "Financial Month": "Nov",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 82.12,
        "Usage PY": 67.23,
        "Target": 62.83,
        "Production CY": 5425327,
        "Production PY": 5044930
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 3,
        "Financial Month": "Dec",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 45.15,
        "Usage PY": 44.36,
        "Target": 41.45,
        "Production CY": 4612380,
        "Production PY": 3746604
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 3,
        "Financial Month": "Dec",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 108.51,
        "Usage PY": 93.61,
        "Target": 87.48,
        "Production CY": 4612380,
        "Production PY": 3746604
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 4,
        "Financial Month": "Jan",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 39.93,
        "Usage PY": 58.3,
        "Target": 54.48,
        "Production CY": 3190793,
        "Production PY": 2938725
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 4,
        "Financial Month": "Jan",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 97.38,
        "Usage PY": 111.09,
        "Target": 103.81,
        "Production CY": 3190793,
        "Production PY": 2938725
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 5,
        "Financial Month": "Feb",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 31.19,
        "Usage PY": 41.06,
        "Target": 38.37,
        "Production CY": 3768347,
        "Production PY": 3175390
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 5,
        "Financial Month": "Feb",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 103.53,
        "Usage PY": 115.71,
        "Target": 108.13,
        "Production CY": 3768347,
        "Production PY": 3175390
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 6,
        "Financial Month": "Mar",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 24.33,
        "Target": 22.73,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 4686034
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 6,
        "Financial Month": "Mar",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 99.38,
        "Target": 92.87,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 4686034
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 7,
        "Financial Month": "Apr",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 28.84,
        "Target": 26.95,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2916675
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 7,
        "Financial Month": "Apr",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 159.67,
        "Target": 149.21,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2916675
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 8,
        "Financial Month": "May",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 149.29,
        "Target": 139.51,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2436180
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 8,
        "Financial Month": "May",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 22.58,
        "Target": 21.1,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2436180
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 9,
        "Financial Month": "Jun",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 16.31,
        "Target": 15.24,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 3307022
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 9,
        "Financial Month": "Jun",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 114.53,
        "Target": 107.02,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 3307022
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 10,
        "Financial Month": "Jul",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 136.08,
        "Target": 127.17,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2783133
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 10,
        "Financial Month": "Jul",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 17.78,
        "Target": 16.61,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2783133
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 11,
        "Financial Month": "Aug",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 21.4,
        "Target": 20,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 3485137
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 11,
        "Financial Month": "Aug",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 128.52,
        "Target": 120.1,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 3485137
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 12,
        "Financial Month": "Sep",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 15.86,
        "Target": 14.82,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 4529008
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 12,
        "Financial Month": "Sep",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 99.09,
        "Target": 92.6,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "'Production Current FY'", "as": "Production CY Legend"},
    {"calculate": "'Production Prior FY'", "as": "Production PY Legend"},
    {"calculate": "'Electricity Target'", "as": "Target Legend"},
    {"calculate": "datum['KPI Name'] + ' PY'", "as": "CategoryPY"},
    {"calculate": "datum['KPI Name'] + ' CY'", "as": "CategoryCY"}
  ],
  "height": 300,
  "width": 600,
  "config": {
    "legend": {
      "orient": "bottom",
      "columns": 2,
      "layout": {"bottom": {"anchor": "middle"}}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "name": "Electricity CY",
          "mark": {"type": "bar", "xOffset": 0, "size": 10, "tooltip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Month Nr",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "Usage CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "title": "Electricity Intensity (kWh / ton Production)"
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "CategoryCY",
              "type": "nominal",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  "Elec from Renewables PY",
                  "Elec from Non-Renewables PY",
                  "Elec from Renewables CY",
                  "Elec from Non-Renewables CY"
                ],
                "range": ["#4496BC", "#5AC8FA", "#39A34B", "#4CD964"]
              },
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            },
            "order": {"field": ["CategoryCY"], "order": ["ascending"]}
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Electricity PY",
          "mark": {"type": "bar", "xOffset": -11, "size": 10, "tooltip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Month Nr",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
            },
            "y": {"field": "Usage PY", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null},
            "color": {
              "field": "CategoryPY",
              "type": "nominal",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  "Elec from Renewables PY",
                  "Elec from Non-Renewables PY",
                  "Elec from Renewables CY",
                  "Elec from Non-Renewables CY"
                ],
                "range": ["#4496BC", "#5AC8FA", "#39A34B", "#4CD964"]
              },
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            },
            "order": {"field": ["CategoryPY"], "order": ["ascending"]}
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "TARGET",
          "mark": {
            "type": "bar",
            "xOffset": 11,
            "size": 10,
            "color": "#FFCC00",
            "tooltip": true
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Month Nr",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
            },
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Target",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "fill": {
              "field": "Target Legend",
              "scale": {"range": ["#FFCC00"]},
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "shared"}, "axis": {"y": "independent"}}
    },
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "name": "Production CY",
          "mark": {"type": "line", "tooltip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Month Nr", "type": "ordinal"},
            "y": {
              "field": "Production CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "title": "Production (ton)"
            },
            "stroke": {
              "field": "Production CY Legend",
              "scale": {"range": ["black"]},
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Production PY",
          "mark": {"type": "line", "tooltip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Month Nr", "type": "ordinal"},
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Production PY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "stroke": {
              "field": "Production PY Legend",
              "scale": {"range": ["red"]},
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent", "stroke": "independent"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you!

If you ever do any VL training, please let me know; feel I could learn a lot form you.

Comment: Apologies David, upon closer inspection it appears the PY (red) line does not confirm to the second Y Axis: [Link](https://imgtr.ee/i/0e5dz)

Comment: I'll add another answer now.